# What is a repository key under Ubuntu and how do they work?

Tags: repository

Most of the time just adding a package repository allows you to download and install packages without a repository key. Also some repositories display their key beside their information so they're easy to find. But

- Why do we need to add keys if we can install packages without them?
- How do they work under Ubuntu?

Comment: I like to add another term for above question, what is the use of "Key Ring"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found a nice explanation from [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community).

- [What are Repositories?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

> "Authentication keys" are usually obtained from the maintainer of the
>   software repository. The maintainer will often place a copy of the
>   authentication key on a public key server such as www.keyserver.net.
>   The key can then be retrieved using the command.

[Apt Authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt)

> `Apt-get` package management uses public key cryptography to
>   authenticate downloaded packages.
>
> - Debian does an excellent job of explaining Secure apt on this wiki
>     page.
>
> What follows is a short summary of the key acquisition and
>   verification process gleaned from Debian's wiki page.
>
> Basic Concepts Public key cryptography is based on pairs of keys, a
>   `public key` and a `private key`. The `public key` is given out to the
>   world; the `private key` must be kept a secret. Anyone possessing the
>   public key can encrypt a message so that it can only be read by
>   someone possessing the private key. It's also possible to use a
>   private key to sign a file, not encrypt it. If a private key is used
>   to sign a file, then anyone who has the public key can check that the
>   file was signed by that key. No one who doesn't have the private key
>   can forge such a signature.
>
> gpg (GNU Privacy Guard) is the tool used in secure apt to sign files
>   and check their signatures.
>
> apt-key is a program that is used to manage a keyring of gpg keys for
>   secure apt. The keyring is kept in the file `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`
>   (not to be confused with the related but not very interesting
>   `/etc/apt/trustdb.gpg`). apt-key can be used to show the keys in the
>   keyring, and to add or remove a key.
>
> Each time you add another apt repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`,
>   you'll also have to give apt its key if you want apt to trust it. Once
>   you have obtained the key, you can validate it by checking the key's
>   fingerprint and then signing this public key with your private key.
>   You can then add the key to apt's keyring with `apt-key add <key>`

Comment: Can I upvote this a hundred times please?  :) Thank you Achu!!

Answer (score 16):

You need repository keys so you can validate you got the package from the person you think you're getting it from.

It's to keep people from injecting bad packages into your updates.

You should add repository keys whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is generally how the process works.
if you got a package in your repository and you want others to be able to download it and also give them the ability to make sure the package comes from you and the content has not been changed then you can add your public key to a public key-server and then do the following.

- Hash the package content
- Encrypt the hash with your private key. (sign it)
- Add the signature to the download package.

Then the user does the following:

1. downloads the package from your repository.
2. decrypts the signature with your public key.
3. hashes the download package minus the signature.
4. compares the hash to the decrypted signature.
   If they match then you can be sure that the package has not been changed and is from the repository owner.
   This process relies on OpenPGP key servers and standard hashing and encryption algorithms.