# How can I install the Opera browser from the terminal?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, repository, browser, opera

Since this .deb bug is causing a lot of issues, I must resort to install the Opera browser using the terminal. Which is just fine, but I also need to add it to the repository for automatic updates.

Since I am no expert at all, I do not know how to perform the full installation of the browser. How do I go about it?

Thanks!

*P.S. Please do not mark this as duplicate, because the other posts dont details how to go about installing Opera with adding it to the repository too for updates. Cheers.*

Comment: Does Opera have a repository? Didn't Opera stop supporting Linux a while ago?

Comment: @muru you can download the 64-bit deb version of the browser from the website. So, I guess it is still going on. However....with this 3rd party .deb issue, I need to install it alternatively.

Comment: The .deb issue is fixed, please `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` http://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1137074_760638

Comment: http://deb.opera.com/ says that the deb package automatically configures the repository (the way Google  Chrome does, I guess). Did you try before asking?

Comment: It's a repetitive question you can see the answer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/169020/how-do-i-download-and-install-opera-in-12-04

Comment: @GreenRoot is correct, the second answer there is the one I gave here, Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/169020/how-do-i-download-and-install-opera-in-12-04

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To install opera via PPA on Ubuntu, run these commands

Setup key with:

```
wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list'
```

Setup package with:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install opera
```

[Source](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/opera)

Alternatively, you can install the .deb via a terminal with

```
sudo dpkg -i path/to/your/deb
```

It already contains the PPA, if anyone else reading this is still facing the .deb issue with `gnome-software`, please report it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206), it is supposed to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you dont mind me asking: what does the setup key?

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/131397/what-is-a-repository-key-under-ubuntu-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: Perfect. It makes perfect sense now. Thanks a lot. By the way, the version you get from the manual installation is old. It wont update online. Asks me to download the deb which cant be installed due to the installation bug. So, this wont solve my problem.

Comment: The bug is gone, see my comment below your question, you could also install the deb via terminal `sudo dpkg -i yourdebhere`.

Comment: The bug is still there. I cant install from .deb. My installation is fully updated and it still persists.Will installing from the deb using sudo dpkg -i also add it to the repository for future updates?

Comment: You should report that here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206 other users confirm it is fixed, the bug only effects the package gnome-software any other package manger `apt, dpkg, synaptic, gdebi` etc will work fine.

Comment: Based on the earlier comment by muru, the deb contains the PPA already, like chrome, so yes.

Comment: Installed the .deb from the terminal. That solved it.