# Unable to install Opera browser on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, opera, 17.04

I tried to install opera by downloading the `.deb` file from opera website. Running `sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_amd64` gave the following results:

```
[sudo] password for user1: 
(Reading database ... 187300 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking opera-stable (44.0.2510.1218) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_amd64.deb"
```

Opera is currently not available in Ubuntu software store or in Software Boutique. I also tried older `opera-stable_44.0.2510.857_amd64.deb` and got similar results. I downloaded the package twice thinking it might be any download error but same result.

Comment: Test this one: `dpkg  --force-all -i opera-deb-file`

Comment: `lzma error: compressed data is corrupt` and `unexpected end of file or stream` strongly suggest the file is indeed corrupt.

Comment: @CelticWarrior How do i download one that is not corrupt? Previously when i update using sudo apt get update command there used to be lots of weak hash values. Does this all mean there is some problem with my Internet connection?

Comment: Either that or a problem in the drive you're saving the files.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Downloads are on ext4 partition, then i move it to NTFS for storage. Installation is done on NTFS drive. Hard disks are relatively new. One is less than 3 years old and other is new one.

Comment: woud be preferable to install right after downloading and then move it. I wouldn't be surprised if that was in fact the cause. Age of the drives is irrelevant: 1. Any hardware can fail at any time but that's not even the most likely underlining cause, 2. **Logical errors** can occur for any number of reasons and those are unrelated with the drive's health.  I would certainly try downloading again, install and only then then move to NTFS (or not, what's the point in keeping an installer that you won't use again?)

Comment: I would also strongly recommend connecting the NTFS drive to a Windows PC and use Windows tools for error correction. A NTFS with logical errors can go unnoticed in Linux for years.

Comment: And you don't need to use the deb either. Opera isn't in the official repos but there's a PPA: https://askubuntu.com/questions/765483/how-can-i-install-the-opera-browser-from-the-terminal

Comment: @CelticWarrior I downloaded it again and installed from downloads folder itself. Still the same errors. I had installed Opera before on Ubuntu 16.10 and it was working fine. It was either from Software Boutique, Ubuntu software or from .deb file. I cant remember. There is a software called opera-stable in  Ubuntu software store which shows up once you double click on the .deb file. But it is not getting installed. Software Boutique has removed opera from their collection at the moment.  So are you recommending to install Opera via PPA?.

Comment: Given the circumstances yes, I'm recommending the PPA. I'm intrigued by your issue, of course, but you being able to install the software you want/need obviously trumps my curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
```

In the file that opens, paste this text:

```
# This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
# as part of regular system upgrades

deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Save file.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Close nano.

Continue running in the terminal:

```
wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install opera-stable
```

Comment: Here are the main results "Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 63F7D4AFF6D61D45
W: The repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease' is not signed. N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: root@PC1:~# apt-get install opera-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opera-stable : Depends: gconf-service but it is not installable
                Depends: libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
                Recommends: pepperflashplugin-nonfree but it is not installable
                Recommends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: Still not able to install. Thanks for the help any way.

Comment: Try this:   "  exec sudo -i "  "  wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -   " "   apt-get -f install  "  "  apt-get install opera-stable "

Comment: "Decryption has failed" message appearing while downloading opera-stable package.  More details given below.

Comment: "exec sudo -i 
[sudo] password for user1: 
root@PC1:~# wget -O - deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -
--2017-04-19 21:07:03--  http://deb.opera.com/archive.key
Resolving deb.opera.com (deb.opera.com)... 185.26.183.130
Connecting to deb.opera.com (deb.opera.com)|185.26.183.130|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3152 (3.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================>]   3.08K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-04-19 21:07:07 (109 MB/s) - written to stdout [3152/3152]

OK"

Comment: apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@PC1:~#  apt-get install opera-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gconf-service gconf-service-backend
  gconf2-common libgconf-2-4 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0
  pepperflashplugin-nonfree

Comment: Suggested packages:
  chromium-browser ttf-mscorefonts-installer ttf-dejavu ttf-xfree86-nonfree
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gconf-service gconf-service-backend
  gconf2-common libgconf-2-4 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 opera-stable
  pepperflashplugin-nonfree
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 52.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 188 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Comment: Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  opera-stable
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu1.1348 [1,028 kB]
Get:2 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free amd64 opera-stable amd64 44.0.2510.1218 [51.5 MB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 gconf2-common all 3.2.6-3ubuntu7 [20.8 kB]

Comment: Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libgconf-2-4 amd64 3.2.6-3ubuntu7 [84.6 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 gconf-service-backend amd64 3.2.6-3ubuntu7 [57.8 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 gconf-service amd64 3.2.6-3ubuntu7 [2,038 B]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libpangox-1.0-0 amd64 0.0.2-5 [41.7 kB]Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libpango1.0-0 amd64 1.40.4-1 [3,258 B]

Comment: Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse amd64 pepperflashplugin-nonfree amd64 1.8.3+nmu1ubuntu1 [5,536 B]
Err:2 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free amd64 opera-stable amd64 44.0.2510.1218
  GnuTLS recv error (-24): Decryption has failed.
Fetched 1,243 kB in 5min 17s (3,911 B/s)                                       
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/pool/non-free/o/opera-stable/opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_amd64.deb  GnuTLS recv error (-24): Decryption has failed.

Comment: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: It seems similar error is happens while installing downloaded .deb package. Running "sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_amd64" gives                                                     "Unpacking opera-stable (44.0.2510.1218) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_amd64.deb (--install):" more details of the results are provided in my question itself. Thank you for your help.